# Even if array for foreach is empty, run it

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, foreach

I've came across a little problem. Well I'm getting from wordpress database some user_meta data, which is stored as array, by declaring variable `$all_meta_for_user = get_user_meta($user_id, 'meta_key', false)`. Then, I'd like to check if some specific data is present, and if so, do something, if not, do something else. I've got somewhere here at stackoverflow a hint, that I can achieve it in that way:

```
foreach($all_meta_for_user as $key=>$val) :
        if (array_key_exists ('some_key', $val) && array_key_exists ('some_other', $val)) { do something } else {do something else } 
endforeach;
```

And that works good, as long as associated 'meta_key' is present in database (which is obvious :)). But what, if it's not? Then, again obviously, foreach is false and it doesn't run.
Basically, I'd like to show content after `else` even if the array is empty. How I can alter my code, to achieve that? I think I could get it working, if I first check `if` array is empty, if no - do code with foreach, if yes - do my else. But the problem is, in my else there's a lot of code, so I'd like to avoid duplicating it.

So, simply, the question is, how to make that in a nice way, that will not double my code :)
Thanks!

PS I really couldn't find appropriate topic name. If someone have a better idea how to name it, please leave a comment so I can change it! Thanks!

Comment: Can't you put the content of your `else` in a function, and call this function in your else OR before your foreach if array is empty ?

Comment: As I stated in the below answer - nope, I can't due to my lack understanding too complicated php code. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your "else" function, and combine that with the if/else idea. That way you won't have any repetition, just function calls:

```
function elseFunction() {
    //do something else
}

if (!empty($all_meta_for_user)) {
    foreach($all_meta_for_user as $key=>$val){
        if (array_key_exists ('some_key', $val) && array_key_exists ('some_other',$val)){ 
            // do something  
        }
        else { 
            elseFunction(); // this is changed
        }
    }
}
else {
    elseFunction();
}
```

Comment: But if I have variables inside that function, I will need to pass them as functions arguments, right? And there are pleeeenty of variables... :<

Comment: Yes, actually wanted to add that to my original answer, but deleted it in the last moment. :) If you have plenty of variables, maybe you can use a single associative array as a parameter: `elseFunction($options)`.

Comment: Well it won't work. Inside that "else" there are references to some classes, variables associated with that classes, and some other nasty things, that I didn't write and I'm too lowlevel to understand that and write it properly, in addition, it's a payment page, which must be really secure, and I can screw that up. Seems I need to double the code at all..

Comment: I disagree, whatever you currently have under that else statement could go into a single function. Nothing changes security-wise. I can't help you more without seeing exactly what you're talking about.

Comment: I managed to do that as I wanted with your snippet, so without going deep, your answer was helpful and the one it works. Thank you a lot!